# j_security_check - can additional parameters be passed for form submits?

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas

Is it possible to pass additional parameters with 'j_security_check' in place?

I would like to pass the the ip address from the login page plus other parameters.

Comment: have you found a solution to this? i'm looking to do the same too.

Comment: Yes I did: set it in TextInputCallback.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as long as you are the recipient of the form post. If you're using the container's built-in FORM authentication you aren't the recipient.